# Getting oauth2 to work with spring-boot and rest

Tags: java, rest, oauth-2.0, spring-boot

I am trying to get oauth2 to work with spring-boot and protect my rest method calls, sans much success.
I have tried using spring-security-oauth2-javaconfig:1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT with rg.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:1.0.0.RC1.

*gradle:
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:1.0.0.RC1")

```
compile ('org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2-javaconfig:1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT'){
    exclude module: 'spring-security-config'
    exclude module: 'spring-security-core'
    exclude module: 'spring-security-web'
}
```

For now I am just trying to get the authentication and resource server working. I have copied and tried to modify the existing sparklr2 sample from the spring-security-oauth2-javaconfig sample.

The last error I get is :"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Bad client credentials
when I run curl  -v --data "grant_type=password&username=marissa&password=koala&client_id=tonr&secret=secret" -X POST localhost:8100/oauth/token.

I understand oauth2 from a beginner's perspective and the paucity of resources with regard to oauth2 with spring-boot and rest make it hard. Any suggestions?

If someone could provide a cookbook like approach to configure oauth2 authentication and authorization to protect a rest api call along with the relevant curl commands, that would be awesome.,

Answer (score 3):

Java config support for oauth2 is work in progress, but you might have more success with [my fork](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-security-oauth-javaconfig). If I were you I'd stick to XML for the oauth2 bits for now. Here's a [bootified sparklr2](https://github.com/scratches/sparklr-boot) with minimal XML. I haven't checked that it works recently but it shouldn't be in bad shape if you update the boot dependencies to 1.0.0.RC2.

Update: the `@Configuration` stuff has moved to the main [OAuth2 repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth), so the fork and its parent are basically redundant now (and will probably be removed soon).

Update: the bootified sample is now also using `@Configuration`.

Comment: Hello Dave, When I click on the fork I get a 404.

Comment: Hi David, I checked out the files from the forked repo and tried to do a gradle build.. (spring-security-oauth-javaconfig.git\branches\feature\admin). All the unit tests failed, most of them with a NoClassDefFoundError. Am I looking in the right place?

Comment: Ignore the gradle build and use Maven, please.

Comment: Hi David, I built the spring-security-oauth2-javaconfig 2.0.0 SNAPSHOT  and deployed it to my local maven repo. Copied the sample sparklr java and resource files as is to a new project. Added a main class to launch the application (SpringApplication.run(RestMain.class)) as I want to run the same as a standalone with embedded jetty. It compiles but then fails when launching:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling

Comment: I can't help you with that. I run it from tomcat in eclipse and it works fine.

Comment: Would you happen to know the difference between running it as a spring -boot standalone with embedded jetty or tomcat, versus running the same as a war in tomcat?

Comment: What do you mean? It's different. The sample in the spring-security-oauth2-javaconfig is not a Boot app, but you could turn it into one I guess (e.g. see [the guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/docs/howto.md#convert-an-existing-application-to-spring-boot)). What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I am trying to implement security with grant-type client_credentials, on a rest service. My rest service is a stand alone jar with spring-boot and embedded jetty.

Comment: And your rest-service wants to issue its own tokens (it's both an Authorization Server and a Resource Server)?

Comment: Yes. My solution is below. It works using password as grant_type, but I am not sure if it is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot... that was very useful. I've created a fork where I've upgraded Spring Boot to 1.1.3.RELEASE (minor changes were needed). You can [find it the fork here](https://github.com/pragone/sparklr-boot)

Comment: @DaveSyer  Is There any documetation about [your project](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-security-oauth-javaconfig)?

Comment: That code was folded into Spring Security OAuth with version 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is what I have done to get it to work that way. I believe it is the right solution (other than using client_credentials for grant_type, but I am not an expert:-) If there is a better solution that would be awesome. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out.

---

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.InMemoryClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2ServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends OAuth2ServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final String applicationName = "restservice";

    @Value("${client_id}")
    private String client_id;

    @Value("${client_secret}")
    private String client_secret;

    @Value("${grant_type}")
    private String grant_type;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .requestMatchers()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .apply(new OAuth2ServerConfigurer())
            .tokenStore(new InMemoryTokenStore())
            .resourceId(applicationName);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(getUserDetails()))
            .and()
            .apply(new InMemoryClientDetailsServiceConfigurer())
                .withClient(client_id)
                .resourceIds(applicationName)
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .authorities("USER")
                .authorizedGrantTypes(grant_type)
                .secret(client_secret);
    }

    private static final Collection<UserDetails> getUserDetails() {
        List<UserDetails> userDetails = new ArrayList<UserDetails>();
        userDetails.add(new User("user", "password", AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(
                        "USER", "read", "write")));
        return userDetails;
    }

}
```

Comment: If that works for you then great. I'm still refactoring this stuff pretty heavily though, so it might break before Spring OAuth 2.0 is released, and even if not it might not be the best solution eventually.